# Does a Metropolis-Hastings chain always obey a central limit theorem?

Tags: markov-chain-montecarlo, markov-process, central-limit-theorem, metropolis-hastings, ergodic

Let $(E,\mathcal E,\lambda)$ be a measure space, $Q$ be a Markov kernel on $(E,\mathcal E)$ with $$Q(x,B)=\int_B\lambda({\rm d}y)q(x,y)\;\;\;\text{for all }(x,B)\in E\times\mathcal E$$ for some symmetric $q:E\times E\to[0,\infty)$, $p$ be a probability density on $(E,\mathcal E,\lambda)$ and $\mu:=p\lambda$.

> Let $\kappa$ denote the transition kernel of the chain $(X_n)_{n\in\mathbb N_0}$ generated by the Metropolis-Hastings algorithm with proposal kernel $Q$ and target distribution $\mu$.
>
> I want to know what we need to assume (if anything) to ensure that for a given $f\in L_0^2(\mu):=\left\{h\in L^2(\mu):\mu h=0\right\}$, there is a $\sigma^2(f)\ge0$ with $$\frac1{\sqrt n}\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}f(X_i)\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}\mathcal N(0,\sigma^2(f))\tag1.$$

I know several conditions ensuring $(1)$, e.g. that $f$ admits a solution $g\in L^2(\mu)$ of the Poisson equation $$f=(1-\kappa)g\tag2$$ or that $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left\|\kappa^nf\right\|_{L^2(\mu)}<\infty\tag3$$ (in which case $g=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\kappa^nf$ is precisely the solution of $(2)$.) For example, if $$c:=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left\|\kappa^n\right\|_{\mathfrak L(L^2_0(\mu))}<\infty,$$ then $(3)$ is satisfied (hence $(1)$ holds for all $f$).

> I wonder, for example, whether $(2)$ or $(3)$ hold for all $f$ or if there are additional assumptions on $(E,\mathcal E,\lambda),p,q$ ensuring this.

If necessary, assume that $(E,\mathcal E)$ is a $\mathbb R$-vector space, $(E,\mathcal E,\lambda)$ is translation-invariant and $q(x,y)=\tilde q(x-y)$ for some $\mathcal E$-measurable $\tilde q:E\to[0,\infty)$. Moreover, you may assume that $\left\{p>0\right\}\subseteq\left\{q(x,\;\cdot\;)>0\right\}$ for all $x\in E$.

*Remark*: Please take note of my related question: [Is the Metropolis-Hastings kernel always aperiodic, irreducible and geometrically ergodic?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/436087/222528).

Comment: @Xi'an Thanks for your comment. With "does not hold in general" you mean not for all $f\in L^2(\mu)$, right?

Comment: @Xi'an Does anything in the paper yield that a CLT holds in general for all $f\in L^2(\mu)$, whenever $\kappa$ is geometrically ergodic? If so, under which assumptions is the Metropolis-Hastings kernel geometrically ergodic?

Comment: @Xi'an I did, but the main result (Theorem 2.1) is considering $E=\mathbb R^d$. Section 3 contains equivalent characterizations of geometric ergodicity in general and some necessary conditions for their $E=\mathbb R^d$ setting. Section 4, which is about the CLT, seems again to consider $E=\mathbb R^d$. Maybe I misinterpreted your first comment, but I don't see any result in the paper which stating that a CLT holds whenever the kernel is geometrically ergodic (there is only a single remark at the end of page 97 which claims this).

Comment: @Xi'an However, in [this book](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F978-3-319-97704-1_21) (Theorem 21.4.7), I've found the claim that if $\kappa$ is geometrically ergodic and $\mu(|f|^2\ln(1+|f|))<\infty$, then $(1)$ holds. Is that what you've got in mind? They explicitly remark that there are geometrically ergodic kernels and square-integrable functions for which the CLT fails (but that doesn't mean that there are MH-kernels for which it fails). In any case, I would really be interested what we need to assume in the setting of my question to ensure geometric ergodicity.

Comment: The functions have to be $L^{2+\epsilon}(\mu)$ [Theorem 1]. Unless the chain is reversible in which case $L^2(\mu)$ is enough, following Kipnis & Varadhan (1986). See also _"Remark 2. It is well known that geometric convergence is not necessary for central limit theorems [however] geometric ergodicity is one of the easiest to check and leads to clean statements"_.

Comment: @Xi'an Which paper do you cite? In the one of Roberts and Tweedie there is neither a Theorem 1 nor a Remark 2. Do you refer to the paper of Kipnis & Varadhan? What's the title? (If it is *Central  Limit  Theorem  for  Additive Functionalsof  Reversible  Markov  Processes  and  Applicationsto  Simple  Exclusions*, there is as well no Theorem 1 or Remark 2.)