# Is the Metropolis-Hastings kernel always aperiodic, irreducible and geometrically ergodic?

Tags: markov-chain-montecarlo, markov-process, metropolis-hastings, ergodic

Let $(E,\mathcal E,\lambda)$ be a measure space, $Q$ be a Markov kernel on $(E,\mathcal E)$ with $$Q(x,B)=\int_B\lambda({\rm d}y)q(x,y)\;\;\;\text{for all }(x,B)\in E\times\mathcal E$$ for some symmetric $q:E\times E\to[0,\infty)$, $p$ be a probability density on $(E,\mathcal E,\lambda)$ and $\mu:=p\lambda$.

> Let $\kappa$ denote the transition kernel of the chain $(X_n)_{n\in\mathbb N_0}$ generated by the Metropolis-Hastings algorithm with proposal kernel $Q$ and target distribution $\mu$.
>
> I want to know under which additional assumptions (if any) $\kappa$ is geometrically or uniformly ergodic. Moreover, is $\kappa$ always $\phi$-irreducible and aperiodic? In particular, I'd like to know whether we can apply Proposition 2.1 and Theorem 2.1 in the paper [Geometric ergodicity and hybrid Markov chains](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.ecp/1453832497).

If necessary, assume that $(E,\mathcal E)$ is a $\mathbb R$-vector space, $(E,\mathcal E,\lambda)$ is translation-invariant and $q(x,y)=\tilde q(x-y)$ for some $\mathcal E$-measurable $\tilde q:E\to[0,\infty)$. Moreover, you may assume that $\left\{p>0\right\}\subseteq\left\{q(x,\;\cdot\;)>0\right\}$ for all $x\in E$.

Comment: Under the condition$$\left\{p>0\right\}\subseteq\bigcap_x\left\{q(x,\;\cdot\;)>0\right\}$$the chain is $\mu$-irreducible and aperiodic.

Comment: @Xi'an Do you have a reference?

Comment: The chain can reach any $\mu$ positive set in one step.

Comment: @Xi'an I see, thanks. Do you think optimizing the rate of geometric ergodicity (with respect to $w$) could be an alternative approach here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/436126/222528?