# Upper bound for the asymptotic variance in the central limit theorem for a Metropolis-Hastings chain

Tags: optimization, markov-chain-montecarlo, markov-process, central-limit-theorem, metropolis-hastings

Let $(E,\mathcal E,\lambda)$ be a measure space, $Q$ be a Markov kernel on $(E,\mathcal E)$ with $$Q(x,B)=\int_B\lambda({\rm d}y)q(x,y)\;\;\;\text{for all }(x,B)\in E\times\mathcal E$$ for some symmetric $q:E\times E\to[0,\infty)$, $p$ be a probability density on $(E,\mathcal E,\lambda)$, $\mu:=p\lambda$ and $\kappa$ denote the transition kernel of the Markov chain $(X_n)_{n\in\mathbb N_0}$ generated by the Metropolis-Hastings algorithm with proposal kernel $Q$ and target distribution $\mu$.

Now let $f:E\to[0,\infty)$ be bounded and $\mathcal E$-measurable with $\mu f=0$ and $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left\|\kappa^nf\right\|_{L^2(\mu)}<\infty\tag1.$$ By $(1)$, we know that $g:=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\kappa^nf\in L^2(\mu)$ is a solution of the Poisson equation $$f=(1-\kappa)g\tag2$$ and hence $$\frac1{\sqrt n}\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}f(X_i)\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}\mathcal N(0,\sigma^2(f))\tag3$$ with $$\sigma^2(f):=2\langle f,g\rangle_{L^2(\mu)}-\left\|f\right\|_{L^2(\mu)}^2=\left\|f\right\|_{L^2(\mu)}^2+2\sum_{n=1}^\infty\langle \kappa^nf,f\rangle_{L^2(\mu)}\tag4.$$

> **Question**: (a) In my application $\kappa$ is depending on a parameter $w$ which I would like to choose in a way such that $\sigma^2(f)$ is minimized (or at least as small as possible) over all possible $f$. Since our $\kappa$ has a special form, I wonder whether we can simplify the expression for $\sigma^2(f)$ in a way easing the minimization problem.
>
> (b) Or, if this is too hard, we may find a (sharp) upper bound which is easier to minimize.

If necessary, assume that $(E,\mathcal E)$ is a $\mathbb R$-vector space, $(E,\mathcal E,\lambda)$ is translation-invariant and $q(x,y)=\tilde q(x-y)$ for some $\mathcal E$-measurable $\tilde q:E\to[0,\infty)$. Moreover, you may assume that $\left\{p>0\right\}\subseteq\left\{q(x,\;\cdot\;)>0\right\}$ for all $x\in E$.